# Override - Display the vendor list in category home page instead of products

Tags: magento-1.7, category, product-list

I have installed separate module for vendors. I need to display the vendor list on each category home page instead of displaying products.

How to display the vendor / manufacturer list from the selected category in category home page?

As I’m new to Magento, I'm just confused that where the product list controller exist. How to display the manufacturer list without modifying the Magento core code?

I have tried with new module for overriding the existing one. But I’m getting blank page only. I just added some sample text.

What is the clear method for overriding the existing coding and design?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Catalog --> Attributes --> Manage Attributes and create an attribute as 'vendor'

   > Note: Make sure to mark the attribute property `Use In Layered
   >   Navigation` as `Filterable (with results)`
2. Assign that to the attribute set which you are using
3. Make sure you have added some vendors into the attribute options
4. Assign one of the options to your products
5. If you refresh the cache and check category page vendors will be shown in layered navigation

Comment: i have separate module for vendors.